# What's the growler?

Tags: glassware

Browsing ALiBaBa International platform I found there are many growlers in the shop. I want to know what a Growler is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the Wikipedia article on it of course: [Growler (jug)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growler_(jug)).

> A growler is a glass, ceramic, or stainless steel jug used to transport draft beer in the United States, Canada, Australia, Brazil and other countries....The significant growth of craft breweries and the growing popularity of home brewing has also led to an emerging market for the sale of collectible growlers.

Answer (score 2):

This is what a growler looks like:
[image: growler]
It typically holds beer (usually 64 U.S. fl oz. or 1,892.7ml). [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growler_(jug)).

Comment: I should note that once the growler is opened, the beer inside only remains fresh (carbonated) for approx. 36 hours (3 days).

Comment: Do you mean *36 hours* (1.5 day) **or** *3 days* (72 hours)?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the correction, @OldPadawan. I'm not sure how the math slipped me on that one:p